# Vba project references same name

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add some reference in my VBA project. In the opened dialog box I see the list of existing references. One reference seems broken (the corresponding file does not exists). I'm trying to add the proper file, but it is not adding to the list, perhaps, because the broken reference has the same name.

So how can I remove this broken ref or how to add the proper ref to the list?

Comment: untick the missing reference?

Comment: unticking don't removes the list item, so the selected file in Add dialog box not adding to the ref list

Comment: maybe work with [**THIS EXAMPLE**](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/add-and-remove-com-references-programmatically/) of deleting and adding references programmatically.

Comment: I apologize if this seems naive, but have you tried unchecking it, closing completely out of Excel, then reopening to add the correct reference?

Comment: The problem solved, admin reinstalled Office. So I could not test your advices, sorry :)